# Hang image off screen without breaking responsivness

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue hanging an image outside of it's container / off screen without it breaking responsiveness of the website. The main issue is that you have to scroll right and left based on how the image is positioned.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve (the product images left and right as you scroll down):
http://invisionapp.com/

Here's where I'm at so far:
http://codepen.io/darcyvoutt/pen/EKRmOZ

The code on the image is:

```
.section {
  height: 505px;
}

.left, .right {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  background: yellow;
}

.right {
  position: relative;  
}

.image {
  max-width: none !important;
  height: 507px !important;
  width: 873px !important;
  display: block;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions for something I left out by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.wrap {
  ...
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
   position: absolute;

  .right & {
    left: 40%;  
  }

  .left & {
    right: 60%;
  }
}
```

Should work with this `HTML`:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="left">
    <img class="image" src="http://sysomos.com/sites/default/files/map_twitter.png" />        
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="section">
  <div class="right">
    <img class="image" src="http://sysomos.com/sites/default/files/map_twitter.png" />        
  </div> 
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: That would just cut it off, so when your screen gets really large, it would have a hard stop on the image. The goal is that it would hang off the screen but the responsiveness wouldn't do a left and right scroll. If you see with the invision website as you make the page wider or more narrow you get more of the image.

Comment: I forked your pen [here](http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/eZKRGR). Is this not what you're after?

Comment: @dvoutt Any luck with the forked pen?

Comment: Will check this all now, Stackoverflow was having issues, it somehow removed all of the comments each time I refreshed the page.

Comment: Thanks my friend, that is what I'm looking for! Now to study and learn what you're doing! :)